# Kendo grid date from and date until when inline editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this kendo grid. For column `dateFrom` and `dateUntil` its possible when I edit the past date from today I able to see the date in grey value? Currently when I edit past date the field will become null.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/ibODAVuW)
code is too long and i cannot display here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully [Updated Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ibODAVuW/3) this will help.

I have made an assumption that you only want the `min date` of the control to be set to before the `current day` if there is a value that already exists and that a new record should not be able to select a date before the `current date`.

All I have done is add a condition onto into the `kendoDateFrom` function to check if the date from this field is before the `presentDate` variable and if it is then set the `min` value of the control to this date for you. I also added a check for a new entry and check if the value is undefined to set it to the current date for you.

```
if(options.model[options.field] != undefined && 
 kendo.parseDate(options.model[options.field], "MM/dd/yyyy") < presentDate){
    presentDate = options.model[options.field]; 
  }
  else 
  {
    presentDate = new Date(); 
  }
```

If your requirement is different then please provide more information in the question to help assist with your requirements.

**EDIT**
So based on your updated requirements I have updated the dojo with what i think you want.

[Modified Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ibODAVuW/7)

I have tweaked the dojo to resolve a couple of issues for you.

1. added a new `currentMinDate` variable which will be used as our min date check.
2. altered the min date checking to resolve the random `blanking` of dates.
3. when a date is in the past `enable` that date but disable all dates between that date and the present date (assuming that is what you want to happen if the date needs to be changed.
4. Added the `parseFormats` setting to ensure it can parse the date format you are providing.
5. Expanded your dataSource so that the update button would save the changes to the local array.

The disable date function does a couple of things:

1. checks to see if the date passed in is null or a date
2. checks to see if the date passed in is less than the present date
3. checks to see if the date passed in is not equal to the current min date

if it resolves all of those to true then it disables the date so it can't be selected, importantly it ensures that it doesn't disable the current selected date in the past so it will select it. If that date was disabled as well then it would be able to select the disabled date as it is treated as invalid.

```
disableDates:function(date){
      console.log('disabling dates function, current passed Date::::', date); 
      console.log(date == currentMinDate, date, currentMinDate); 
      if(date && date.getDate() < presentDate.getDate() && 
         date.getDate() != currentMinDate.getDate())
      {
        console.log(date,currentMinDate,  'disabled'); 
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        console.log(date,currentMinDate,  'not disabled'); 
        return false; 
      }
      
    },
```

I have left my comment statements in so you can see what is happening.

Hope this helps you out now.

Comment: TQ for your time. it slightly off. Let me try to explain again. Basically in edit mode I cannot edit the `past date` from `presentDate`, if date already past from today date, only able to display the date in disable mode but I still can update the date start from today onwards. Plus I notice a something weird in your demo, for example if I clicked on `edit` and `cancel` button again and again I notice sometime the date display null a value (it only happen for `past date`).

Comment: So if you want to be able to edit the past dates why are you setting the min date of the controls to the present date?

Comment: Because it can be used during Add New Record. Based from my original post and demo. For example when I edit `Data A` I can see the dateFrom and dateUntil. currently it display blank because of the date control.

Comment: maybe i should rephrase my question. What is the purpose of setting the `minDate` on the control. Why do you want to disable dates before a certain date either that be a past (already entered date) or the present Date for a new record? Can new records have a `past date` when they are added for the first time?

Comment: (1).  I want to use `minDate` setting during Add New Record. Meaning it only can add `presentDate` onward.
(2). And my requirement  date that has been past from `presentDate` cannot be edited. but it can be display in disable mode.  Plus, selecting `presentDate` onwards still allowed it any changes.

Comment: I have updated my answer with new dojo so hopefully that answers your problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to help me. Really appreciate.